# Add a new row to R dataframe - but if does not exist already?

Tags: r, dataframe

Is there any possiblity to add a new row that does not exist already in a dataframe? I create a big dataframe (100k records) with different combinations of the variables (randomly selected) and I want to add them to the existing dataframe with a condition: all they must be different (at least one variable must be different).

Comment: Maybe rbind, then unique?

Comment: Try `df1 <- rbind(df1, setdiff(df2, df1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following if, for example, the dataframe, `df1`, may or may not exist and you want want append dataframe, `dr2` to it:

```
rbind(if(exists("df1")) df1, df2)
```

But this can often be avoided by simply creating an empty data frame first.  For example if your dataframe contains a single columns `x` which is of type character, than you could probably do:

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = character())
rbind(df1, df2)
```